# JProfiler for StandAlone Servers

Tags: java, jprofiler

Iam using jprofiler for a while for my tomcat applications. Now i have made a HttpServer Application using java HttpServer (with out using anu container). Is it possible to configure jprofiler for that stand alone application.

Answer (score 0):

Any JVM can be profiled by adding the `-agentpath...` VM parameter to it. To get help on the exact form of the `-agentpath...` VM parameter, invoke

Session->Integration Wizards->New Remote Integration

in JProfiler's main menu.